# Conditional Formatting in cell A1 based on value in cell N1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
   A          N
1  My Test    0
```

How can I make MyTest a red font if the value in cell N = 0? I explored the conditional formatting but it doesn't seem it allows me to set the condition on the value of a different cell other than itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is what you do.  Go to `Home > Styles > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula ...`, and this is the formula you can try:

```
=($N1=0)
```

The key is the `$` sign, I only set the `$` sign in front of `N` because I don't want the `N` gets changed when I drag down the formula.  You will need to make sure if this is what you want.

[image]

Then I have this setting applies to `=$A$1:$A$5` cells in my example and you will need to adjust it accordingly.  Hope this helps but let me know for any issue.

Comment: As I mentioned in an earlier comment too; I'd suggest `=AND(($N1=0),NOT($N1=""))` as this will handle blank cells too

Comment: Do this instead: `=(($N1=0)*NOT($N1=""))`.  In conditional formatting, sometimes it won't work well with complex `AND/OR.  This is easier to avoid the issue.

Comment: Ah interesting, I didn't know this... Thanks :)

Comment: Thak you all, this along with other one helped me make this clear and work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting as you see below.

explanation - 
L1 - connected to the first cell in the chosen range (for K1 it use L1, for K2 is use L2 etc..),  2 the value it's equals to.

[image: conditional formatting example]

Comment: Its not just that it is the first cell choosen, it is the active cell of the selection.  I believe your relative references will be updated based on movement to the active cell at the time the condition is made.  I could be wrong as i have not paid too close attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use fixed/dynamic cells appropriately.

The affected area would be:

```
=A1 'Note no $s
```

The formula would be:

```
=N1=0 'Again, no $s... i think F4 will actual sort through the options of where the $ goes, when in the field
```

If you were to do an entire row of color, based on the formula =N1=0, your affected range would be:

```
=$A1
```

Then set the color for when true.

---

It helps to select the affected range BEFORE setting a new rule.  If you didn't select the affected range before setting the rule, go back in AFTER setting the rule formula.

Comment: `=AND((N1=0),NOT(N1=""))` would be the proper formula for that, as you should handle blank cells too

Comment: @Maldred Would it not be OR() not AND()?

Comment: No, you can try it yourself, you'll have to use AND()

Answer (score 1):

You can try do it using VBA code.
Add the follow procedure to `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Range("N1").Value = 0 Then
    Range("A1").Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' 3 indicates Red Color
  End if
End Sub
```

This procedure will run every time something in your WorkSheet changes.
If you need to run only when N1 is changed, you can add the follow code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$N$1" Then
    If Target.Value = 0 Then
      Range("A1").Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' 3 indicates Red Color
    End If
  End if
End Sub
```

Hope it helps